# How to modify value of object inside deleting object? [MVC, JSON, JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a big MVC project and this is my API controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using AutoMapper;
using Library.Dtos;
using Library.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Library.Controllers.Api
{
    public class RentalsController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public RentalsController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        // GET /api/rentals
        public IHttpActionResult GetRentals(string query = null)
        {
            var rentalsQuery = _context.Rentals
                .Include(r => r.Customer)
                .Include(r => r.Book);

            var rentalDtos = rentalsQuery
                .ToList()
                .Select(Mapper.Map<Rental, RentalDto>);

            return Ok(rentalDtos);
        }

        // GET /api/rentals/1
        public IHttpActionResult GetRental(int id)
        {
            var rental = _context.Rentals.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);

            if (rental == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(Mapper.Map<Rental, RentalDto>(rental));
        }


        [HttpDelete]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteRental(int id)
        {
            var rentalInDb = _context.Rentals.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            if (rentalInDb == null)
                return NotFound();

            var book = _context.Books.Single(c => c.Id == id);

            book.NumberAvailable++;

            _context.Rentals.Remove(rentalInDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Web.Http;
using AutoMapper;
using Library.Dtos;
using Library.Models;

namespace Library.Controllers.Api
{
    public class NewRentalsController : ApiController
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public NewRentalsController()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult CreateNewRentals(NewRentalDto newRental)
        {
            var customer = _context.Customers.Single(c => c.Id == newRental.CustomerId);

            var books = _context.Books.Where(m => newRental.BookIds.Contains(m.Id)).ToList(); //SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Id IN (1,2,3 etc)

            foreach (var book in books)
            {
                if (book.NumberAvailable == 0)
                    return BadRequest("Ksiazka jest niedostepna.");

                book.NumberAvailable--;

                var rental = new Rental
                {
                    Customer = customer,
                    Book = book,
                    DateRented = DateTime.Now
                };

                _context.Rentals.Add(rental);
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Index View, where I am executing deleting:

```
@model IEnumerable<Library.Models.Rental>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Wypozyczenia";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Rentals</h2>

<table id="rentals" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Klient</th>
        <th>Tytul</th>
        <th>Data wypozyczenia</th>
        <th>Akcje</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $("#rentals").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/rentals",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "Customer.Name"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "Book.Name"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "DateRented"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "Id",
                        render: function (data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-rentals-id=" + data + ">Zwrot zamowienia.</button>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            $("#rentals").on("click", ".js-delete",
                function () {
                    var button = $(this);

                    if (confirm("Na pewno?")) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/rentals/" + button.attr("data-rentals-id"),
                            method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                //datatable methods - row, remove and draw
                                table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });

        });
    </script>
}
```

And, lastly, this is my Rental class (Model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Library.Models
{
    public class Rental
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public Book Book { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateRented { get; set; }

        public DateTime? DateReturned { get; set; }

    }
}
```

The problem is - I want to DELETE the RENTAL object from my DB, but before doing that, I want to modify value of one of the objects (Book) inside the RENTAL object; I want to increment value "NumberAvailable".

Book class (model):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Library.Models
{
    public class Book
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Genre Genre { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kategoria")]
        [Required]
        public byte GenreId { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

        [Display(Name ="Data publikacji")]
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ilosc w magazynie")]
        [Range(1, 40)]
        public byte NumberInStock { get; set; }

        public byte NumberAvailable { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is it even possible?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to alter a book using the same id as the rental. Your query for the book should use rentalInDb.Book.Id. That will get you the record you need to modify.

Comment: It doesn't work either : ( Tried it and code simply doesnt execute, thus it compiles w/o any warnings. It couses POST 400 Error.

Comment: Are you able to debug? A bad request should tell you why. Is the id not getting parsed from the URL? Also returning Ok without any parameters can be interpreted incorrectly be the js code, I recommend returning Ok(true).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 book.NumberAvailable++;

 _context.Books.Add(book);
 _contextEntry(book).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

 _context.Rentals.Remove(rentalInDb);
 _context.SaveChanges();
 return Ok();
```

You need to add your object to list of modified to persist on your database.

Comment: I don't have access to this project now :( But asap I will try your solution.

Comment: Okay let me know if it works as reference also to others with the same problem as yours.